# iOS App development : View visible but not active

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Please help! It seems to simple, but, sorry, I 'have' to ask, as it's not working. I have a main view with a UITableView. On swiping, am adding a subview which has a picker and a button. It works fine: I swipe & the subview appears in front of the main view, but when I click the picker or the button, nothing really happens in the subview; instead the components in the main view (which is beneath the subview) get called! Am saying this for sure, because, in the main view, I have a picture beneath the added-subview (tapping the picture opens a new view). Now, when I tap the picker in the subview (the picture is beneath it in the main view), the picture gets tapped & the new view  opens up!  How is this possible?

This is the subview (in Interface Builder)

[image]

Here's my code snippet:

In my **MainViewController.m** (viewCtrlrFilter is the subview added when the user swipes in the main view)):

```
....
self.viewCtrlrFilter = (ViewController_Filter *) [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kNameViewCtrlrFilter];
...
// This is called when the user pans/swipes
// This does work fine; the subview gets added & is visible
[self.viewCtrlrFilter initializeView];
[self.viewCtrlr.view setFrame:CGRectMake(310.0, 220.0, 243.0, 208.0)];
[self.view addSubview:self.viewCtrlrFilter.view];
...
```

From **ViewController_Filter.h** :

```
...
// This implements the Picker Delegate & DataSource
// which I have wired to the picker in IB
@interface ViewController_FilterPhotographers : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
...
// This is called when the button in the subview 
// (screenshot above) is pressed
// It's wired through the IB
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender;
...
```

From **ViewController_Filter.m** :

```
-(void) initializeView {

    self.myPicker.delegate = self;
    self.myPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.myPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    CGRect rect = self.myPicker.frame;
    rect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
    self.myPicker.frame = rect;
    self.myPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.625,0.625);
    [self.myPicker becomeFirstResponder];
}
...
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"hi");
}
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeView];
}
...
```

When the user swipes, the subview does get added (the picker & button are seen), but when I click the button, the IBAction method isn't getting called. Instead, funnily, the component in the main view (beneath the subview) is getting called!

Comment: is `userIntactionEnable` for your `ViewController_Filter` ?

Comment: Thanks, Inder. Yes, it is enabled for the ViewController_Filter.view, the UIPicker, the UIButton in IB. I checked it again now. So, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works now! Looks like setting the datasource & delegate for the picker view from both the code & IB was a problem. I set it from IB & removed it from code. It works fine now!